# Difference between %time and %%time in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

What is the difference between `%time` and `%%time` in a Jupyter Notebook Cell?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**%time**  measures execution time of the next line.

**%%time** measures execution time of the whole cell.

For instance:

```
%time
a = 1
time.sleep(5)
```

> CPU times: user 8 µs, sys: 0 ns, total: 8 µs
> Wall time: 16.9 µs

```
%%time
a = 1
time.sleep(5)
```

> CPU times: user 1.13 ms, sys: 2.11 ms, total: 3.24 ms
> Wall time: 5 s